# How to implement recursive function in Racket?

Tags: racket, tail-recursion

I am trying to create a function called lcm-from-factors that computes the Lowest Common Multiple of two numbers (m and n) The inputs to the function are m-co-groups and n-co-groups, which list all the prime factors and their powers. For instance, for m= 2970 and n= 163,800, we will have:

m-co-groups= ’((2 1) (3 3) (5 1) (7 0) (11 1) (13 0))
n-co-groups= ’((2 3) (3 2) (5 2) (7 1) (11 0) (13 1))

These are returned by a function called co-factor which has been given to me. I have written the code but the function is not compiling because I believe I did not implement the recursion properly. I'd appreciate any help in figuring out what I am doing wrong. My code is as follows.

```
    (define (lcm-from-factors m n)
        (let-values (((m-co-groups n-co-groups) (co-factor m n)))
            (define (recurse m-co-groups n-co-groups)
                (let* ((a (first(m-co-groups)))
                      (b (first(n-co-groups))))
                   (cond ((>= (rest(a)) (rest(b)))
                         (+ (expt (first(a)) (rest(a))) (recurse (rest(m-co-groups)) (rest(n-co-groups)))))
                         (else (+ (expt (first(b)) (rest(b))) (recurse (rest(m-co-groups)) (rest(n-co-groups))))))))))
```

Comment: From what I'm seeing `(co-factor m n)` have to evaluate to two lists of procedures since you are applying  elements (`(a)` and `(b)`) and those procedures should produce pairs since you are trying to `first` the results?

Comment: Yes the function I have been given does return two lists as shown for m=2970 and n=163,800.

Comment: However, I can't comple (first (m-co-groups)) for some reason?

Comment: `(m-co-groups)` means calling `m-co-groups` as a procedure. If it isn't a procedure you'll get an error. None of the variables should ever be called as procedures..

Comment: No m-co-groups is the returned list. Co-factor is the procedure I believe.

Comment: m-co-groups= ’((2 1) (3 3) (5 1) (7 0) (11 1) (13 0)).  It returns a list, where each element is a pair.

Comment: Again.. When you enclose a variable in parentheses i Scheme you are treating it as a procedure with no arguments.. Eg. if `a` was `(lambda () 10)`, then `(a)` becomes 10. If `a` is `(2 1)` you get an error saying `(2 1)` is not a procedure since you are effectively calling `('(2 1))` I'm guessing you loose lots of errors by removing excess parentheses. eg `(first m-co-groups)` instead of `(first (m-co-groups))` which sould require `m-co-groups` to be a procedure like `+` is .

Comment: Thank you I have removed all the extra parentheses. The error is still there though. The error message is as follows:

Comment: "begin (possibly implicit): no expression after a sequence of internal definitions"

Comment: It's because you are defining a procedure recurse, but you are not making use of it by calling `(recurse m-co-groups n-co-groups)` as the last expression in the `let-values`. You can do both in one form with named let `(let recurse ((m-co-groups m-co-groups) (n-co-groups n-co-groups) ... )`

Answer (score 0):

The following is a stepping stone to get you started.
The code handles the specific situation where m and n has the same prime factors.
It is your job, to figure out how to handle the other cases.

```
#lang racket
(require math/number-theory)

(define (co-factor m n) (values (factorize m) (factorize n)))
(define (exponent power) (second power))
(define (base power)     (first power))

(define (lcm-from-factors m n)
  (let-values ([(m-co-groups n-co-groups) (co-factor m n)])
    (define (recurse m-co-groups n-co-groups)
      (cond
        [(and (empty? m-co-groups) (empty? n-co-groups))  1]
        [(empty? m-co-groups)                             'something-1]
        [(empty? n-co-groups)                             'something-2]
        [else
         (define a-power (first m-co-groups))
         (define b-power (first n-co-groups))
         (define a-base  (base a-power))
         (define b-base  (base b-power))
         (define a-exp   (exponent a-power))
         (define b-exp   (exponent b-power))
         (cond 
           [(= a-base b-base)   (* (expt a-base (max a-exp b-exp))
                                   (recurse (rest m-co-groups) (rest n-co-groups)))]
           [(< a-base b-base)   'something-3]
           [(> a-base b-base)   'something-4])]))
    (recurse m-co-groups n-co-groups)))

(define x (* (expt 2 3) (expt 3 4)))
(define y (* (expt 2 1) (expt 3 5)))

(lcm-from-factors x y) ; gives 1944
(lcm x y)              ; gives 1944
```